# Получение почты средствами PHP через IMAP

Tags: php, imap

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Есть E-mail'ы, логины и пассы к своей почте. Охота средствами PHP с каждой почты получать E-mail'ы. Просто подключиться к почте по IMAP, затолкать все письма в простой PHP массив. Без всяких извратов, без удалений писем, просто подключаемся -> делаем массив с письмами. Что то в роде:

```
$mails = array(
    array('дата-время','от кого','тема','текст');
    array('дата-время','от кого','тема','текст');
    array('дата-время','кому','тема','текст');
    array('дата-время','кому','тема','текст'); 
    ...
);
```

И сам уже пытался, и гуголь мучал. Посте двух дней поисков, странно, но больше одного письма, из всего списка, получить не могу. Подскажете с кодом?

update:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$login='***@mail.ru'; $pass='***'; $server='pop.mail.ru'; $port=110; $nevedomaya_xernya=10;
$f=fsockopen($server,$port,$errno,$errstr,$nevedomaya_xernya);

if(!$f){die("Не удается подключиться к pop.mail.ru: [$errno] $errstr");}
echo $s=fgets($f); if (strpos($s,'+OK')!==0) die('ошибка подключения');
fwrite($f,"USER $login\r\n");
fwrite($f,"PASS $pass\r\n");
echo $s=fgets($f);
if (strpos($s,'+OK')!==0) die('ошибка авторизации');
fwrite($f,"TOP 1 1000\r\n");
$msg='';
$head='';

while (false!==($s=fgets($f))){
    if ($s===".\r\n") break;
    if ($s=="\r\n" && !$msg)
    $msg=' ';
    if (!$msg) $head.=$s;
    else $msg.=$s;
}
echo trim($head);
echo "\n\n---конец заголовков---\n\n";
echo trim($msg);
?>
```

Comment: ну хоть ссылкой рабочей порадуйте. у меня агония уже.

Comment: @mixalef ну вы хоть укажите, как получаете письма? Использую PHPmailer и всё ок.

Comment: да уж перебрал тысячу примеров из инета. А смысл в неправильном то? Про PHPmailer - нашел только отправку 1 письма. А так, что бы получить их, да еще и все. Можете сказать? Или кодом напугать?

Comment: @mixalef каюсь, про PHPmailer соврал. Но вроде документация предостаточная по этому протоколу: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.imap.php

Comment: обновил. собственно максимум, что по той документации написал. та же штука. 1 письмо получить могу, все - не могу (

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Порядок действий примерно такой:

1. Устанавливаем соединение с почтовым сервером с помощью функции [imap_open](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-open.php)
2. Получаем заголовки писем в ящике с помощью функции [imap_fetch_overview](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-fetch-overview.php). Теперь у нас есть массив писем, в котором содержится msgno, from, to, date, subject и другие параметры, которые мы обычно видим в почтовом клиенте, когда просматриваем ящик.
3. Ну дальше, зная msgno каждого письма получаем его содержимое (текст, вложения) с помощью функций imap_fetchbody, imap_fetchheader, imap_headerinfo, imap_fetch_overview и другие... Все функции [здесь.](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.imap.php)

Приводить пример кода не буду, в оф. документации достаточно примеров для каждой из функций. Если не получиться, пишите, будем думать дальше вместе :)

Comment: Ну, да хоть начнем с пункта 1. Емайл и пасс - рабочие, пишем всего 1 строку:

    $mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $email, $password) or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

в итоге получаем:

    Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream 

- ест-но форумы - ест-но ругань на хостинги, что это их ошибки. перебрал 4ре разных хостинга -> ничего. Пробовал другой порт подставлять, и отдельно без ssl

 - подскажите как дальше быть?

Comment: Возможно у вас не включена поддержка OpenSSL в PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php
Если вы не админ сервера, то можно попросить хостера установить поддержку ssl.

А вообще, лучше всего развернуть сервер на локалке (виртуалке) и установить все что надо. И только после того как приложение заработает на вашей машине, искать подходящего хостера.

Если Вам не принципиально использовать gmail, то попробуйте ukr.net. Он позволяет использовать незащищенное соединение на 143 порт. У меня соединение устанавливалось без проблем. На gmail, к сожалению, не пробовал.